# Как сделать вывод инлайн кнопок в случайном порядке(в три ряда) Телеграм бот Python Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я делаю телеграм бота на питоне, и мне нужно вывести инлайн кнопки в случайном порядке, что я и сделал, **НО** никак не могу сделать чтобы они распологались в три ряда по три кнопки(3*3). Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать

```
list_buts = [("1", "field_1"), ("2", "field_2"), ("3", "field_3"),
             ("4", "field_4"), ("5", "field_5"), ("6", "field_6"),
             ("7", "field_7"), ("8", "field_8"), ("9", "field_9")]
random.shuffle(list_buts)
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
for text, data in list_buts:
   markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=text, callback_data=data))
await call.message.answer("Случайный порядок в три ряда?", reply_markup=markup)
```

[image: Вот что даный код выводит]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Юзайте `insert` вместо `add`

```
for text, data in list_buts:
   markup.insert(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=text, callback_data=data))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы сохранили мне ОЧЕНЬ много нервных клеток :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте свойство row_width (кол-во колонок), как показано ниже.

```
def buy_menu(is_url=True, url='', bill=''):
qiwi_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
if is_url:
    btn_url_qiwi = InlineKeyboardButton('Оплатить', url=url)
    qiwi_menu.insert(btn_url_qiwi)
btn_check_qiwi = InlineKeyboardButton('✔️Проверить оплату', callback_data='check_'+bill)
qiwi_menu.insert(btn_check_qiwi)
btn_cancel_qiwi = InlineKeyboardButton('Отмена', callback_data='cancel')
qiwi_menu.insert(btn_cancel_qiwi)
return qiwi_menu
```

Comment: В даной ситуации, это свойство не работает. Данные для инлайн кнопки берутся со списка и выводятся в случайном порядке. Цикл for как раз-таки их выводит и он не смотрит на это свойство. Но проблема уже решена, спасибо)